# How to skip downloading package while using gradle?

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, download

I'm compiling elasticsearch.
Because of the network is not very stable, every time the "./gradlew localDistro" command reaches the downloading of ml-cpp-8.2.0-SNAPSHOT.zip,it will fail after long download before finish.
I have downloaded the package from browser, then how to skip download it while compile it by gradle

Comment: Finally I found a mirror of the repository from my location. But still this is a problem need to find a way to get through for who can't find a mirror.